# ¿Como cambiar el idioma de phpBB en Google Cloud Platform instalado con Bitnami?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Según la documentación de bitnami.
He descargado el paquete de lenguage que necesito https://www.phpbb.com/languages/.

"Después de descargarlo, descomprima el archivo .ZIP y pegue el idioma / y los estilos / directorios en su instalación de phpBB."

El problema es que la instalación se realiza en una VM de Compute Engine y no tengo ni idea de donde está la instalación de phpBB y no se como subir archivos de mi máquina local a una ruta concreta de la VM.

He visto que existe un comando para copiar archivos entre la VM y la maquina local.
gcloud compute scp pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

¿Alguien me ilumina?

Answer (score 0):

Una vez descargado el paquete de idioma.
Nos conectamos a la máquina virtual por SSH. Desde la consola de Google se puede subir el ZIP que hemos descargado directamente. Arriba a la derecha de la consola encontramos la opción "subir archivo" y se sube en el directorio actual o en el /home.
Lo último es descomprimir el ZIP y mover la carpeta dentro de "htdocs", luego de entrar en el panel de control de PHPbb, instalamos el idioma nuevo que ya debería aparecer como opción.